# how can I update one field in Django rest framework in abstract user model

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, abstract-class

how can I update one field in the Django rest framework in the abstract user model can someone help me I want to Update device_id in my abstract user model I want to only update device_id dield without updating other field and I do not know I have to create another view or not or I should add update to serializers
here is my code

models.py

```
class User(AbstractUser):
is_student=models.BooleanField(default=False)
is_teacher=models.BooleanField(default=False)
mobile_no=models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True)
device_id=models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True)

USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'

def __str__(self):
    return self.username

class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural="1.User"

@receiver(post_save, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
def create_auth_token(sender, instance=None, created=False,**kwargs):
    if created:
       Token.objects.create(user=instance)
```

serializers.py

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model=User
    fields=['id','username','mobile_no','is_student','device_id']
```

views.py

```
class StudentSignupView(generics.GenericAPIView):
serializer_class=StudentSignupSerializer
def post(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
    serializer=self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    user=serializer.save()
    return Response({
        "user": UserSerializer(user, context=self.get_serializer_context()).data,
        "token": Token.objects.get(user=user).key,
        # "message":"account created successfully"
    })


class TeacherSignupView(generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class=TeacherSignupSerializer
    def post(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        serializer=self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user=serializer.save()
        return Response({
        "user": UserSerializer(user, context=self.get_serializer_context()).data,
            "token": Token.objects.get(user=user).key,
            # "message":"account created successfully"
        })

 class CustomAuthToken(ObtainAuthToken):
    def post(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        serializer=self.serializer_class(data=request.data, context={'request':request})
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user=serializer.validated_data['user']
        token,created=Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
        return Response({
            'token':token.key,
            'user':UserSerializer(user, context=self.get_serializer_context()).data,
            'is_student':user.is_student
         })
```

Answer (score 0):

you could create a view a like this([ref](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#updateview))

```
from django.views.generic.edit import UpdateView
from myapp.models import Author
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

User = get_user_model()

class UserUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = User
    fields = ['device_id']
```

Comment: what about URL should I put the id or not?

Comment: yes you will have to pass the user id and the device id